# Updated equivalent of `JWTClaimsSet.setAllClaims`

Tags: java, jwt

I initially used `nimbus-jose-jwt` `v2.26` in which I used the following `setAllClaims` method as follows:

```
JWTClaimsSet jwtClaimsSet;
Map<String, Object> additionalIdTokenClaims;
jwtClaimsSet.setAllClaims(additionalIdTokenClaims);
```

Now that I have updated the version to `5.8.0`, the methods are different and I can't find the equivalent method to `setAllClaims` in the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/5.8).

I'm guessing it should be something like the following, but I can't find the way to do it:

```
JWTClaimsSet.Builder jwtClaimsSetBuilder;
Map<String, Object> additionalIdTokenClaims;
jwtClaimsSetBuilder.setAllClaims(additionalIdTokenClaims);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, there is no equivalent method in the new version. Instead, it can be implemented to iterate the map and add the claims as follows (Java8):

```
additionalIdTokenClaims.forEach((k, v) -> jwtClaimsSetBuilder.claim(k, v));
```